# Associating 2 models correctly to another model in the create action of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

many questions similar to my problem have been asked and I have looked into them. Replicating their answer has not solved my problem.

I have 3 models:

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scoreboards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :scoreboard
end
```

Think of scoreboard as an article where users can leave comments. My goal is when I create a new instance of `@comment` using a form, it is associated to both `User Model`(which would be the user that is posting the comment) & `Scoreboard model`(the scoreboard whose show page the form is located on). Then, I want to be able to render a partial on the `scoreboard#show` page which would be `<%= render @scoreboard.comments.reject(&:new_record?) %>`. In that partial(`_comment.html.erb`), I want to display the comment body and display the name of user which is associated with that comment. The name should be a link to the profile page of the user associated with that name(`/users/show.html.erb`).

So far this is what I have:

The migration for the comments to show that foreign id columns have been created:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.text :reply
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :scoreboard, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :comments, :users
    add_foreign_key :comments, :scoreboards
  end
end
```

The `/scoreboards/show.html.erb` View which holds the form and the render code:

```
<div class= "comment-section">
  <%= form_for [@scoreboard, @comment] do |f| %> 
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
       <%= f.text_field :body, class: "form-control" %>  
        <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: " form-3 btn btn-primary" %>         
        <% end %>

  <%= render @scoreboard.comments.reject(&:new_record?) %>

 </div>
```

The partial(`/comments/_comment.html.erb`) which is where I want to display a link with a name of the user who is associated with the comment.

```
 <p>
   <%= #code to display comment.user.name with a link to User Show page %>
   <%= comment.body %>
 </p>
```

The `create method` for `Comments Controller`:

```
def create
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
     @comment = @scoreboard.comments.build(comment_params)
     @comment.user = current_user
     if @comment.save
         redirect_to scoreboard_url(@comment.scoreboard_id) 
     else
       render 'new'
     end
    end
```

The `show method` for the `Scoreboards Controller`:

```
def show
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.build #this line is for another model not mentioned
  @comment = @scoreboard.comments.build
 end
```

In order to display the name for the user associated with the comment, in the partial that was rendered(`_comment.html.erb`), I tried the code `<%= comment.user.name %>` which resulted in the following error: `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`.What could I be doing different to fix this issue so the name can be displayed of the user?

Comment: Please check weather the value for `user_id` in `comments` table is saved while creating.

Comment: I believe it is because when I try the code <%= comment.user_id %> in the partial, it successfully display the id of the user who created the comment. Is there any other way to check this? Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is associated to both `User` (which would be the user that is posting the comment) & `Scoreboard` (the scoreboard whose show page the form is located on)

You'll do something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :scoreboards do
   resources :comments, only: [:create]
end

#app/controllers/scoreboards_controller.rb
class ScoreboardsController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find parmas[:id]
       @comments = @scoreboard.comments.new
   end
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find params[:id]
      @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new comment_params
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :reply, :etc).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
   end
end
```

This gives you the ability to call `@comment.user` as follows:

```
#app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
<%= comment.body %>
<%= link_to "Written by #{comment.user.id}", comment.user %>
```

---

Your error will only be caused by two possibilities:

> 1. Your `@comment` has no associated user
> 2. Your `comments#create` action is not populating the user into the comment

In both instances, the problem will be that you have no associated `user` for your comments. As such, your primary goal is to make sure you can associate them as you need.

The first step will be to make sure your `user_id` foreign key is being correctly populated in your database. We use `PHPMyAdmin` with our dev MYSQL db - if you have something similar, check out what's being saved. If it's there, it means your `@comment` object is not loading it; else you're not saving it to the db.

If it's not being saved, the problem is likely with the params (both ones which are being *pushed* and ones being *permitted*). You need to make sure your `user_id` is getting populated no matter what.

If it is being saved, it means your calling `@comment` will not be loading the `user` associative object. The likely cause of this will be a bad association, although it could also be that your `@comment` object is not being populated with the associated data.

Comment: Thank you so much. this worked exactly how I wanted. Except, I wanted `"Written by #{comment.user.name}"`(which works!). Btw, it was @comment* and params* in scoreboard controller. I realized this error when I copied and pasted haha.